# How to update the Location in CLLocationManager based on Time Interval

Tags: iphone, cllocationmanager

I have to update the newLocation in CLLocationManager Delegate depending on certain time  interval

Answer (score 0):

The location manager updates based on distance moved, not based on time interval.  It doesn't make sense to spend CPU time updating every x seconds if the location has not changed.

Comment: But that's the problem, we know that the location have changed. Because we move !!
But the location manager don't send an update.

Comment: @progrmr So, it's not possible to call  didUpdateToLocation after evey 3 minutes rather than checking fro frequent updates ?